# Prove $ \{v, Tv\} $ is lin. ind.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

There exists the following question in my linear algebra textbook.

Let $ T:V\rightarrow V $ be a linear transformation where $ V $ is a linear space over $ \mathbb{R} $, $ dimV = 3 $, $ T \neq 0 $ and $ T^3 + T = 0 $.

I already proved that $ T $ is not an isomorphism.
The next question is to prove that if $ v \in V \setminus KerT $, then $ \{v, Tv\} $ is linearly independent.

Here is what I have so far:

We shall solve the equation:

$ \lambda v + Tv = 0 $

$ T^2(\lambda v + Tv) = 0 $

$ (\lambda T^2)v + T^3v = 0 $

We know that $ T^3 + T = 0 $ and therefore

$ Tv + T^3 v = 0 \Rightarrow $

$ Tv = \lambda T^2(v) \Rightarrow $

$ (I - \lambda T) v \in KerT $.

But I don't know how to continue, could you please give me a clue? I can't use eigenvalues!

Comment: You say "I can't use eigenvalues", but of course when you write $\lambda v + T v = 0$ with $v \neq 0$, you're implicitly saying that $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue ;-)

Comment: I meant, I can't use theorems about eigenvalues, diagonalization, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $Tv=cv$ for non-zero $c\in \mathbb R$, then $-cv=-Tv=T^3v=c^3v$. Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: Then $ c^3 = -c \Rightarrow c^3 + c = 0 \Rightarrow c(c^2 + 1) = 0 \Rightarrow c = 0 \lor c = \pm i \notin \mathbb{R} $. Therefore, $ c = 0 $ - contradiction. ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @talopl There's no contradiction, it's a direct proof that $Tv$ and $v$ are linearly independent.